# 3D Animation in Python: Moving Point and Trajectory

Tags: python, python-2.7, animation

I am switching from Matlab to Python, so I am a relative beginner. What I would like to get is a 3D animation of a point moving in space, say along a helix for simplicity, and a history of its trajectory.

Based on this example http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_3danim.html, I have come with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.animation as animation

###############################################################################
# Create helix:
def make_helix(n):
    theta_max = 8 * np.pi
    theta = np.linspace(0, theta_max, n)
    x, y, z = theta, np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)
    helix = np.vstack((x, y, z))

    return helix

# Update AUV position for plotting:
def update_auv(num, dataLines, lines) :
    for line, data in zip(lines, dataLines) :
        line.set_data(data[0:2, num-1:num])
        line.set_3d_properties(data[2,num-1:num])
    return lines

# Update trajectory for plotting:
def update_trj(num, dataLines, lines) :
    for line, data in zip(lines, dataLines) :
        line.set_data(data[0:2, :num])
        line.set_3d_properties(data[2,:num])
    return lines
###############################################################################

# Attach 3D axis to the figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)

# Define no. data points and create helix:
n = 100
data = [make_helix(n)]

# Create line objects:
auv = [ax.plot(data[0][0,0:1], data[0][1,0:1], data[0][2,0:1], 'ro')[0]]
trj = [ax.plot(data[0][0,0:1], data[0][1,0:1], data[0][2,0:1])[0]]

# Setthe axes properties
ax.set_xlim3d([0.0, 8*np.pi])
ax.set_xlabel('X')

ax.set_ylim3d([-1.0, 1.0])
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

ax.set_zlim3d([-1.0, 1.0])
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

ax.set_title('3D Test')

# Creating the Animation object
ani_auv = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_auv, n, fargs=(data, auv),
                              interval=50, blit=False) #repeat=False, 
ani_trj = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_trj, n, fargs=(data, trj),
                              interval=50, blit=False) #repeat=False, 
plt.show()
```

Now, this code shows what I am trying to achieve (show the moving body as a point and the history of the trajectory at the same time), but it has two major problems:

1. The trajectory is recalculated at every time step, which is inefficient, but computing power should not be a problem;
2. The bigger problem is there is a misalignment between the point and trajectory. I think the reason for it is due to the lower computational time associated with the calculation of the position of the simple point.

An alternative could be what they do here: [Animate a python pyplot by moving a point plotted via scatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31303601/animate-a-python-pyplot-by-moving-a-point-plotted-via-scatter), but to be honest, I would prefer to find a way to create an animation with time stamps. That way, I have to calculate the trajectory only once and can update the position of the point at every new time step.

Thank you for the help!